# Perform xml transformation and filtering in java

Tags: java, xml, pipeline

I'd like to filter a couple of nested xml elements, evaluation of their attributes. For this purposes I'm searching a efficient and lightweight java api or framework.

The main requirements are:

- filtering of element bodies, based
  on some pattern or condition
- event based XML transformation

My first idea was apache jelly, but jelly has an ungly side effect. It removes CDATA tags and thats an unwanted behaviour.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I implemented the filterchain using dom4j and xpath. 
I decided for this api because it is quite handy if you got to move a number of branches inside one document and it's build in xpath facilitates finding the wanted elements.

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 1):

Go simple and try [SAX](http://www.saxproject.org/).

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure [JXPath](http://commons.apache.org/jxpath/) has filtering capabilities. Worth having a look at probably :)

Comment: JXPath uses XPath syntax to navigate POJO hierarchies, and isn't directly XML related

Answer (score 0):

Would XSLT work for you? There are java libraries built in for this, and the layout is such that you can setup sections only when certain tags and/or conditions are met. Then again, you have to learn XSLT.

Answer (score 0):

I use and recommend xquery over xslt. Both are functional languages and take some getting used to. Saxon supports both. See http://saxon.sourceforge.net/